# Запуск очереди от имени пользователя

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

В приложении на laravel 5.8 при обработке задачи из очереди возникает необходимость получить аутентифицированного пользователя auth()->user(), который во время запуска очереди отсутствует (null).

**Подробности:**

1 Некий юзер инициирует процесс импорта вызовом метода Import\ImportController@init;

2 В этом методе проверяется и парсится переданный файл import.csv, для каждой строки которого в очередь отправляется задача обработки строки; Задания ресурсоёмкие, т.к. выполняют обработку изображений: ресайз и наложение водяных знаков;

3 По окончанию обработки файла пользователю выдается сообщение об успешности постановки заданий в очередь;

4 После обработки изображений в заданиях происходит сохранение моделей в базу данных;

5 В процессе сохранения модели в методе creating() обсервера вызывается метод setCreator(), устанавливаюций параметр creator_id, использующий хелпер auth():

```
 /**
 * set setCreator from auth user
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function setCreator(): self
{
    $this->creator_id = auth()->user();
    return $this;
}
```

6 Модель, естесственно, можно сохранить и с помощью метода ModelController@store - там хелпер отрабатывает как надо.

7 Подробности несколько упрощены и передача текущего пользователя в задачу мне показалась излишне громоздкой. В данный момент вбил костыль: постановка очереди регистрируется в логах, а creator_id ставлю system_user, но заказчиком было озвучено, что в этом поле должен быть id именно инициатора импорта.

В тестах можно воспользоваться $this->actingAs($user), а как решить проблему в очередях?

Есть ли способ запустить задачу из очереди под определенным пользователем?

Comment: Если это поможет - то необходимо запустить задачу от имени пользователя, аутентифицированного в момент постановки задачи.

Comment: Вы не можете в задаче вызывать методы auth и т.д. так как задача является асинхронной операцией во время выполнения которой никто не авторизован!! и сессии то же нет. Единственное что вы можете сделать это передать в конструктор задачи объект пользователя который при запуске задачи был авторизован на тот момент например MyTask::dispatch(Auth::user()); и внутри уже использовать данную модель.

Comment: Если при запуске никто не авторизован, то и задача не сможет получить объект авторизованного пользователя!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение (как неожиданно!) в [мануале](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#other-authentication-methods).

Правда с небольшим отличием:

производится не запуск очереди от имени пользователя, а непосредственно при выполнении метода handle() происходит аутентификация необходимого пользователя по переданному id:

```
public function handle(): void
{
    Auth::loginUsingId($this->initiatorId);

    // теперь можно воспользоваться auth()->user()
}
```

что, впрочем, и требовалось, судя по описанию вопроса.

Надеюсь кому-то пригодится.

Answer (score 1):

вы можете легко в очередь передавать id пользователя, и уже в самой очереди доставать пользователя из репозитория. Либо передавать саму модель пользователя, тут уже как пожелаете

Comment: Спасибо, но это не то. нужен не пользователь, а именно аутентифицированный пользователь для получения возможности использования хелпера. Пока вбил костыль - при отсутствии авторизованного пользователя подставляется специально созданный пользователь system.

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо всем откликнувшимся, но, к сожалению, предложенные варианты решают лишь малую часть вопроса. Полностью решить проблему невозможно.
Вопрос закрыт

Comment: Это не проблему невозможно решить, это вы неправильно поняли очереди и их использование в Laravel. Чтобы с этим разобраться, необходимо правильно составить логику приложения.

Comment: @Sevastopol': Спасибо за совет, но попробуйте вникнуть в написанное. Выбрать лучший ответ из неправильных невозможно.

Comment: @MoloF: Верно ли утверждение: "В Laravel нет способа запустить задачу из очереди под определенным пользователем"? Если утверждение верно, то ставьте его ответом - отмечу.

Comment: @Yakoffka я не могу утверждать что нельзя запустить задачу из очереди под определенным пользователем, я не вижу конкретной задачи к которой это применимо. Я уверен что ваш вопрос решается другим способом и есть другие варианты как добиться желаемого результата. Опубликуйте новый подробный вопрос что вы используете, что вы делаете и что вы хотите получить в итоге.

Comment: @MoloF: расширил вопрос, указав подробности. Прошу подтвердить необходимость создания нового вопроса.